# forwarding the NAs when searching with grepl in R

Tags: r, grepl

Is there a way to search with `grepl` and not overwriting the NAs?

```
grepl('test', c(NA, 'test','bla',NA))
# [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

I would love to get `NA  TRUE FALSE NA`.

Comment: `c(NA, 'test','bla',NA)=='test'` ?

Comment: @Cath I assume OP wish to do a more complex search than equality :p (but then the Q should include a more complete example)

Comment: @Tensibai ah... from the importance of a representative example... ;-p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `grepl`, we can try the `is.na` to get the expected output

```
as.logical(NA^is.na(v1) * grepl("test", v1))
#[1]    NA  TRUE FALSE    NA
```

or with `ifelse`

```
ifelse(is.na(v1), NA, grepl("test", v1))
#[1]    NA  TRUE FALSE    NA

ifelse(is.na(v2), NA, grepl("test", v2))
#[1]    NA  TRUE FALSE    NA  TRUE
```

Or with `replace`

```
replace(grepl("test", v2), is.na(v2), NA)
#[1]    NA  TRUE FALSE    NA  TRUE
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c(NA, 'test','bla',NA)
v2 <- c(v1, "test run")
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you can use `str_detect(string, pattern)` from Hadley Wickham's **stringr** package:

```
> library(stringr)
> str_detect(c(NA, 'test','bla',NA), 'test')
[1]    NA  TRUE FALSE    NA
```

Note that the arguments are in reverse order compared to `grepl()`.